# python - Return a value captured in a function and add it to a csv file

Tags: python, csv, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am currently working on a piece of code and I cant seem to get it working no matter what I try.

What I am trying to do is return a value to a function which can then be accessed outside of the function by calling the function in a different section of the code. I want the value to then be passed into an area of the code were I am creating a csv.

Here is the function that contains the values I need.

```
def handleNotification(self, cHandle, data):

    # Calculating the temperature in celsius and printing the value to the cmd
    if cHandle == 24 and data[0] == '\x02':
        temp_string = binascii.b2a_hex(data)
        temp_val = temp_string[2:10]
        temp_exp = temp_val[-2:]
        temp_mes = temp_val [:-2]
        temp_mes_swap = "".join(map(str.__add__, temp_mes[-2: :-2], temp_mes[-1: : -2]))
        final_temp = int(temp_mes_swap, 16)*0.1
        temp = format(final_temp)
        #print temp
        print ('Temperature: {0} Celsius'.format(final_temp))
        return temp
```

As you can see I am trying to return the value temp to the function. I am then trying to call this function and the value temp in the following code. I plan to pass the temp_reading variable into the csv.

```
csv_data = retrieveData()
temp_reading = csv_data.handleNotification(24, temp)
```

When I execute the code I get the following error "float object has no attribute '*getitem*'".

The temp variable is defined as a float at the top of my script.

I am new to python so it is quite possible that I am missing something but no mater what I try it wont work. Any help is appreciated :)

UPDATE: I have resolved this issue by creating another function underneath the handleNotification function and passed the value for temp into it. I was then able to call the new function and assign it to a variable that I could use in the csv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way the function is defined and arguments are passed,

```
cHandle = 24
data = temp
```

In the line

```
if cHandle == 24 and data[0] == '\x02':
```

`data[0]` is wrong syntax, since `data` is a float (you mentioned `temp` to be a float which is the same as `data`).

Hence, the error.

Comment: Ok so what do you suggest instead? I changed data[0] to data but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Seems your code expects a temperature string in  a particular format. So, data[0] should be there. Find out what the format is.

Comment: It expects the temperature to be read in as hexadecimal format. The value is being passed in by a BLE device.